# Windows Phone 8.1 scrolling image gallery

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating an image gallery that users can view by swiping an image to the left or right (horizontally) to see the next (or previous) image. Ideally, the image would snap into place like a hub section. I don't want to use a hub, however, due to memory concerns, as well as a hub isn't meant for this purpose.

I'm getting the first image to load, but I cannot swipe or move to another image in the collection. The first image loads, and I cannot slide it left or right.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Here's my relevant code:

**ViewModel**

```
Images = (await _service.GetImages(sectionId))
         .Where(i => "Image".Equals(i.Type))
         .SelectMany(sr => sr.Images
               .Where(ii => "Standard Resolution".Equals(ii.Type))
         .ToList();
```

(This above code successfully returns a list of image objects.)

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="ImagesLayout" Grid.Row="1" Height="250">
        <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Url}" Stretch="Fill" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good article that outlines exactly how to implement an image carousel for Windows Phone 8.1. http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/windows-81-image-carousel